# Saving files with different names

Tags: python, pandas

I want to save these printed 'ex2' tables to excel with different names. This print 3 different tables and I need to save these tables in three different excel files. I tried to make this in this way

```html
b= [{'A': (1.9047619047619044, 1.9047619047619047),
  'B': (0.9523809523809522, 0.9523809523809523),
  'C': (2.857142857142857, 2.857142857142857),
  'D': (1.4285714285714286, 1.4285714285714286),
  'E': (1.9047619047619044, 1.9047619047619047),
  'K': (3.809523809523809, 3.8095238095238093),
  'L': (2.380952380952381, 2.380952380952381),
  'N': (17.142857142857142, 17.142857142857142)},
 {'A': (2.5, 2.5),
  'B': (1.25, 1.25),
  'C': (3.75, 3.75),
  'D': (1.875, 1.875),
  'E': (2.5, 2.5),
  'K': (5.0, 5.0),
  'L': (3.125, 3.125),
  'N': (22.5, 22.5)},
 {'A': (2.7777777777777777, 2.2222222222222223),
  'B': (1.3888888888888888, 1.1111111111111112),
  'C': (4.166666666666666, 3.3333333333333335),
  'D': (2.083333333333333, 1.6666666666666667),
  'E': (2.7777777777777777, 2.2222222222222223),
  'K': (5.555555555555555, 4.444444444444445),
  'L': (3.4722222222222223, 2.7777777777777777),
  'N': (25.0, 20.0)}]
```

```py
for element in b:
    sawst = df2[df2.operations.str.contains('cut', case=False)]
    startt = sawst['start'].tolist()
    duet = sawst['due'].tolist()
    oper = sawst['operations'].tolist()
    colNames = ['koszt[pln]', 'czas[h]']
    ex = pd.DataFrame(element).T  # transpose to look just like the sheet above
    ex.columns = colNames
    ex['czas[h]'] = ex['czas[h]'].round(2)
    urzadzenie.append(maszyny)
    # ex['czas[h]']=pd.to_datetime(ex['czas[h]'], unit='h').dt.strftime('%H:%M')
    ex2 = ex.assign(operacje=oper, start=startt, due=duet)
    ex2.index.name = 'orders'
    print (ex2)
    ex2.to_excel(r'C:\Users\DELL E6510\Desktop\XD\zasoby\nowe\ZASOBY_zam{}.xlsx', format(element))
```

And I got the error: InvalidWorksheetName: Excel worksheet name must be <= 31 chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possible solution**

**Replace:** `ex2.to_excel(r'C:\Users\DELL E6510\Desktop\XD\zasoby\nowe\ZASOBY_zam{}.xlsx', format(element))`

with

`ex2.to_excel(r'C:\Users\DELL E6510\Desktop\XD\zasoby\nowe\ZASOBY_zam{}.xlsx', format(round(element["A"][0], 3)))`

Comment: I got: 
TypeError: type dict doesn't define __round__ method

Comment: Updated answer, you need to access a `value` of the dictionary to perform the **round** on.